# Can I use Presentation API on Ionic Framework app on Android for multiple monitor support?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, multiple-monitors, presentation, presentation-api

I am trying to build an Ionic Framework App for an Android device that also has a secondary monitor.

I found the Presentation API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Presentation_API

and a simple demo:

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/presentation-api/

which I successfully tested on a Windows laptop with an external HDMI screen.

I do not have the Android device yet, so instead I tried using the "simulate second screen" function in the Developer Options of a Samsung Galaxy Tab A tablet. However, when I go to the demo page, it does not detect my secondary display. In the specifications it says that Chrome versions above 48 should support this, and I am running Chrome 73, but at least on my device the simulated secondary screen only mirrors the main screen, and is not detected in the browser.

Has anyone ever used this successfully on Chrome for Android? Am I doing something wrong here? Is the simulated display different from an actual external display?

Comment: Any news on this? How did you resolve the problem?